# Avoid contracting braced if into two lines with clang-format

Tags: clang-format

I'm currently running clang-format version 3.8.0 (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) against C++11 code.

The behavior I'm trying to avoid:

clang-format seems to want to contract the following if statement:

```
        if (condition_one || condition_two)
        { 
            return; 
        }
```

into two lines:

```
        if (condition_one || condition_two)
        { return; }
```

I wouldn't mind it if it was a single line, or if it just didn't touch it at all.  But contracting the braces onto a second line like this isn't really the style I'm going for.

I haven't found any particular settings that would seem to cause this behavior, but it happens nonetheless.

Current `.clang-format` file:

```
---
Language:        Cpp
AccessModifierOffset: -4
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: false
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: false
AlignEscapedNewlinesLeft: true
AlignOperands:   true
AlignTrailingComments: false
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: true
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: true
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: true
BinPackArguments: true
BinPackParameters: true
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BraceWrapping:
  AfterClass:      true
  AfterControlStatement: true
  AfterEnum:       false
  AfterFunction:   false
  AfterNamespace:  false
  AfterObjCDeclaration: false
  AfterStruct:     false
  AfterUnion:      false
  BeforeCatch:     false
  BeforeElse:      false
  IndentBraces:    false
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: None
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: false
ColumnLimit:     80
CommentPragmas:  '^ IWYU pragma:'
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: true
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 4
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
DerivePointerAlignment: true
DisableFormat:   false
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
ForEachMacros:   [ foreach, Q_FOREACH, BOOST_FOREACH ]
IncludeCategories:
  - Regex:           '^<.*\.h>'
    Priority:        1
  - Regex:           '^<.*'
    Priority:        2
  - Regex:           '.*'
    Priority:        3
IndentCaseLabels: true
IndentWidth:     4
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: false
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false
MacroBlockBegin: ''
MacroBlockEnd:   ''
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: None
ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 2
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: false
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: false
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 1
PenaltyBreakComment: 300
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 120
PenaltyBreakString: 1000
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 1000000
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 200
PointerAlignment: Left
ReflowComments:  false
SortIncludes:    false
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 2
SpacesInAngles:  false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: true
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
Standard:        Auto
TabWidth:        4
UseTab:          Never
...
```

Comment: Which clang-format version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There are two settings which affect this specific case:

- `AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType`: Should be `true` for your case. This will always break after the `return` statement.
- `AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine`: In your settings it's true. The whole statement would have been on the same line if there was no `BraceWrapping: AfterControlStatement: true` which causes break after the `if` and the condition. Set this to `false`.